# how to auto-click a firefox pop-up notification

Tags: firefox, popup

I want to auto click the "allow" action on a popup notification of firefox. But I don't know how to do it? Can someone help me about this?

Thanks

like [a pop-up window sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_popup_notifications), I want to automatically click "Share Location" action by script. I try to use Selenium, but I don't think selenium can do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable pop up in firefox goto

```
      Tools>>Contents>>
```

and then you will see the first option to be Block pop-up Window ,you can select it to block or deselect to enable pop-ups.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to automatically click a "allow" action on a popup window, not disable or enable bolck pop-up window.

Comment: then i think you are looking for a keyboard shortcut for allow pop up for a particular site,when it shows a yellow bar for options,then you can press tab till it reaches option menu then press enter and scroll to select appropriate option and then press enter.

Comment: Thanks. But where is a yellow bar? How can I verify there is a popup window appear? For I'm doing a web automation test, I want to verify the browser will prompt me to download a plugin  through the popup window